# How to avoid native authentication popup in AIR on Mac?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, macos, air

In AIR on Mac, when I send login creds to a service and they're incorrect, AIR displays a native popup window to try logging in again without dispatching an error event. Twitter provides a header (suppress_response_codes=true), which returns any error as a status 200 with the error message. I'm using HTTPService to connect to a service without a header like this. Are there any properties or headers I can send to avoid this popup?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to prevent the popup window by switching to URLLoader and using URLRequest.authenticate=false.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle all the events in your class the message will not appear to the user.
Try to declare every event-related methods.

Comment: I have all events handled and it still prompts the popup. Any other ideas?